# sudo apt-get update not connecting to repositories - GPG signature invalid / repository has no release file

Tags: apt, software-installation, updates, software-center, update-manager

Every time I run `apt-get update`, it spits out this. And when I try downloading things from `apt-get install` or **Ubuntu software center**, it doesn't work. Please help. Thanks.

```
    Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates Release' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwendal-lebihan-dev/hexchat-stable/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/audacity/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### For `BADSIG` error

It could be there is incorrect signature, to fix this, open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 40976EAF437D05B5
```

Where **`40976EAF437D05B5`** is your bad signature key, use this command to resolve corresponding error by just replace last key.

Then, to avoid similar problem to occur again, you may want to clear `apt` software cache.

```
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt update
```

#### For `does not have release file` error

The error implies that you have incompatible repository, such as:

1. [Deadsnakes](http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes) (DISCONTINUED)
2. [HexChat stable](https://launchpad.net/~gwendal-lebihan-dev/+archive/ubuntu/hexchat-stable)
3. [Audacity](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntuhandbook1/+archive/ubuntu/audacity)

Simply removing these repository would get rid the error, use `--remove` arguments on `add-apt-repository`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/audacity
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes-python2.7
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/hexchat-stable
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but it seems to me that your GPG cache is corrupt. try running

```
    sudo apt-key update
```

That will restore the keys for the Ubuntu repos. The third party repos, I have no idea how to fix. I think the dirty solution would be to run

```
    sudo apt-get update --allow-unauthenticated
```

I would really advise against this though. It throws any security you have in running updates out the window.